# foreach loop error throws outofbounds exception after taking input

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to take input in an initialized array using for-each loop, but it throws out of bounds exception

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Hello {

 public static void main(String[] args){

     int[] a = new int[9];

     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

     for(int i:a)
    {
      a[i]=sc.nextInt();
    }
      System.out.println("entered elements:");
      for(int x : a)
    {System.out.println("  "+a[x]);
    }
 }
}
```

after taking input, it gives out of bounds exception

Comment: In the first loop `i` will always be 0 and for the second loop x will be whatever value you entered last which might be  > 8. I suggest you delete this code and start over. Using `while` is probably the best option for the first loop and otherwise  classic `for(int i = 0; ...)` type of loop is another option

Answer (score 2):

This

```
 for(int i:a)
{
  a[i]=sc.nextInt();
}
```

stores every input integer at `a[0]` as array is initialized with 0. So that is essentially bad. But despite that:

Do

```
  for(int x : a)
{ System.out.println("  "+a); }
```

So you wont get out of bounds exception.

And in general, what *I think you wanted to do is*

```
int[] a = new int[9];

 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

 for(int i=0;i<a.length.i++){
  a[i]=sc.nextInt();
}
  System.out.println("entered elements:");
  for(int x : a){
     System.out.println("  "+x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("  "+a[x]);
```

should be

```
System.out.println("  "+x);
```

And instead of using for each just use simple for loop like following:

```
class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = new int[9];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("entered elements:");
        for (int x : a) {
            System.out.println("  " +x);
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the values and not the indices.

```
int[] a = new int[9];  is equal to

int[] a = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

Therefor is i always 0 and you are only storing your input in a[0]

```
  for(int i:a){
       a[i]=sc.nextInt();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

Let's quickly go over what I think you tried to do at a high level:

- Initialise an array (of size 9)
- Iterate through the array with a loop and set the values in the array at the position in the loop, as the next integer in the scanner
- Finally, iterate through the array once more, printing out the elements at each position in the array

However, there are few reasons it won't doesn't work as expected:

Your array is an array of type int, which is a primitive type (and therefore not considered an object in Java) -so it can't be null like an object. Therefore, the values in your array are assigned a default value of 0 ({0,0,0,0,etc}).

With this in mind, the first loop:

```
     for(int i:a)
     {
       a[i]=sc.nextInt();
     }
```

Is going to loop through the array - but every value in your array is 0,
so it will just keep setting:

```
 a[0]=sc.NextInt();
```

This can be fixed by using this loop condition instead, which iterates based on the length of the array - with i representing a position in the array, not a value in the array:

```
         for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
         {
           a[i] = sc.nextInt();
         }
```

Finally, your last print is causing the out of bounds exception as you're iterating again on the values in the array - and let's say sc.nextInt() in the previous loop returned the value 15 - when you try loop up position a[15] - it doesn't exist and therefore you see the out of bounds error.

You can fix this by simply printing out the current value in the array:

```
  for(int scannerValue : a)
   {
        System.out.println(scannerValue);
   }
```